# PHP array grabbing random value to insert

Tags: php, arrays

I try to grab random value from array `':server' => $gg`

My insert line looks fine

```
$insertLogSQL -> execute(array(
    ':user' => $_SESSION['username'], 
    ':ip' => $host, 
    ':port' => $port, 
    ':time' => $time, 
    ':method' => $method, 
    ':stopped' => 0, 
    ':server' => $gg));`
```

But my value code is buggy and makes page say currently unable to handle this request.

```
// the array
$arrX = array("Kay", "Joe","Susan", "Frank");

// get random index from array $arrX
$randIndex = array_rand($arrX);
$gg = $arrX[$randIndex];
```

Errors are:

> Notice: Undefined variable: winner in C:\xampp\htdocs\New\boot.php on line 63
>  Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'server' cannot be null in C:\xampp\htdocs\New\boot.php:63
>  
>   Stack trace:
>
> ```
>    #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\New\boot.php(63): PDOStatement->execute(Array) 
>    #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\New\boot.php on line 63
> ```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: This page isn’t working 127.0.0.1 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: winner in C:\xampp\htdocs\New\boot.php on line 63

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'server' cannot be null in C:\xampp\htdocs\New\boot.php:63 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\New\boot.php(63): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\New\boot.php on line 63

Comment: The error message mentions `$winner`, but there's no variable by that name in your code.

Comment: Is `$winner` the real name of `$gg`? The error is pretty clear, you're not setting `$winner` correctly. Is the code that grabs the random element before the code that executes the query? Are they in the same variable scope?

Comment: Post the entire function, it's impossible to tell what you're doing wrong from the snippets.

Comment: Problem is with the $winner variable I think